# User::getvar gives undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, string, static-methods

I have a piece of code that doesnt seem to be working because it gives an error on reading out of the array.

Im using this function to get a variable from the users array:

```
static function getVar($v) {
  if(in_array($v, user::$struc)) {
    return self::$user[user::$struc[$v]];
  }
  else die("getVar: ".$v." > is unkown in struc");
}
```

now i am getting an error when i use for example:

```
user::getVar('Klantnummer');
```

It gives me a notice :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Snackbar\System\Modules\User.php on line 79
>   Line 79 is this: return self::$user[user::$struc[$v]];

I've put a var_dump on the login to see whether it puts the data into the array and that is working fine as shown below:

```
array(9) {
  ["Klantnummer"]=> string(1) "2"
  ["LoginNaam"]=> string(5) "Thimo"
  ["Wachtwoord"]=> string(128) "SPOOFED OUT 
  ["Voornaam"]=> string(5) "Thimo" 
  ["Achternaam"]=> string(7) "Franken" 
  ["Adres"]=> string(10) "Poortugaal" 
  ["Huisnummer"]=> string(2) "11" 
  ["Plaats"]=> string(10) "Poortugaal" 
  ["Postcode"]=> string(6) "3176VE"
}
```

Now here is the `$struc` array:

```
    static $struc = array(
    "Klantnummer"   => 0,
    "LoginNaam"     => 1,
    "Wachtwoord"    => 2,
    "Voornaam"      => 3,
    "Achternaam"    => 4,
    "Adres"         => 5,
    "Huisnummer"    => 6,
    "Plaats"        => 7,
    "Postcode"      => 8
);
```

Anyone got an idea what could be wrong?

The full code:

```
<?php
class user {


static $struc = array(
    "Klantnummer"   => 0,
    "LoginNaam"     => 1,
    "Wachtwoord"    => 2,
    "Voornaam"      => 3,
    "Achternaam"    => 4,
    "Adres"         => 5,
    "Huisnummer"    => 6,
    "Plaats"        => 7,
    "Postcode"      => 8
);

static $ses = "loggedin";
static $hash = "whirlpool";
static $user = array();

static $usda = "userdat";

static function login($username, $password) {
    $host =     'localhost';
    $database = 'Snackbar';
    $user =     'root';
    $password = '';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $msg = "Regelnummer: ".$e->getLine()."<br/>
                Bestand: ".$e->getFile()."<br/>
                Foutmelding: ".$e->getMessage()."";

        trigger_error($msg);
    }


    $HashPW = hash('whirlpool', $_POST['Password']);
    $Hashed = strtoupper($HashPW);

    $Login = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Klanten WHERE LoginNaam = :Naam AND Wachtwoord=:Wachtwoord");

    $Login->bindParam(':Naam', $_POST['Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 45);
    $Login->bindParam(':Wachtwoord', $Hashed, PDO::PARAM_STR, 129);

    $Login->execute();


    if($Login->rowCount() > 0) {
        self::$user = $Login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION[self::$ses] = true;
        $_SESSION[self::$usda] = self::$user;
        var_dump(self::$user);
        print("Succesvol ingelogd");

    }       
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[self::$ses] = false;
        $_SESSION[self::$usda] = false;
        print("Verkeerde login naam en/of wachtwoord"); 
    }
}
static function logOut() {
    $_SESSION[self::$ses] = false;
    $_SESSION[self::$usda] = false;

    self::$user = null;
}
static function loggedIn() {
    return $_SESSION[self::$ses];
}
static function getVar($v) {
    if(in_array($v, user::$struc)) {
        return self::$user[user::$struc[$v]];
    }
    else die("getVar: ".$v." > is unkown in struc");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getVar()` has an error. `self::$user` does not exist which makes `self::$user[user::$struc[$v]]` undefined. What you really would like to access is `self::$struct[$v]` instead.

```
static function getVar($v) {
  if(in_array($v, self::$struc)) {
    return self::$struc[$v];
  }
  else die("getVar: ".$v." > is unkown in struc");
}
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4f3a3ada495ec97e16f55b4132b99c9c1f4b4f9 for a working example.

Comment: static $user = array(); is on top of my code and that is where the data gets saved into when a user logs in. return self::$user[users::$struc[$v]]; So this should get the data that matches $user and is also in $struc. So just putting self::$struc[$v] wouldnt work. I need the data from the $user array